# Does this sentence that uses "gestalt" make sense?

Tags: word-usage

I am trying to talk about the aesthetics of an architecture firm's work in a cover letter I am writing.

Here is the sentence:

> Your beautiful interior details and furniture design that encourages material exploration and utilizes collaboration between designers, builders, and users, shows through to the gestalt of your projects.

Does this make sense?

Comment: That begs the question:  Does any use of "gestalt" make sense.

Comment: @HotLicks Raises the question.

Comment: No, it doesn't.

Comment: It makes sense, but you may wish to check your subject-verb agreement. On the other hand, perhaps architects don't worry too much about such things.

Comment: @Ricky - "Begs the question" is correct.

Comment: Aside from the gestalt, "that" in this sentence is used as a restrictive relative and what's wanted is a non-restrictive relative--", which"

Comment: The sentence runs on a bit, it would be more understandable if you split it up. But we're not supposed to provide proofreading/editing service here.

Comment: @Barmar, I know you closed the question, but I was interested in trying to help you.  I don't think you did use "gestalt" properly.  A gestalt is formed by the way the parts come together in the viewer's perception.  Various elements form into a coherent gestalt, often one that is seen as more than the sum of its parts.  Design elements of the firm's unique working and aesthetic style are perceived, but it is not right to say they show through. Elements coalesce to form the gestalt.    See https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/gestalt

Comment: @Palizsche I didn't ask the question.

Comment: Sorry, Barmar.  I obviously didn't look closely at who the OP was.

Comment: @Rocket Man, even though the question was closed, I was interested in trying to help you. I don't think you did use "gestalt" properly. A gestalt is formed by the way the parts come together in the viewer's perception. Various elements form into a coherent gestalt, often one that is seen as more than the sum of its parts. Design elements of the firm's unique working and aesthetic style are perceived, but it is not right to say they show through. Elements coalesce to form the gestalt. See en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/gestalt – Palizsche